# Odoo 8 - how to change page title?

Tags: title, odoo

i was wondering how to change page titles and remove Odoo from it?

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/change-login-page-title-34874
I tried this but i found nothing.

Comment: Is your question about Odoo-proper itself or about a website powered by Odoo CMS?

Comment: My question is about Odoo itself.

Answer (score 6):

The title is set using the standard html `<title` tag in [/addons/web/views/webclient_templates.xml, in the `web.layout` template](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/web/views/webclient_templates.xml#L121):

```xml
<template id="web.layout" name="Web layout">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
            <html style="height: 100%">
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
                    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                    <title>Odoo</title>
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/web/static/src/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/static/src/css/full.css" />
                    <t t-raw="head or ''"/>
                </head>
                <body t-att-class="body_classname">
                    <t t-raw="0"/>
                </body>
            </html>
        </template>
```

So you can change it in a xml file in a custom module, like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>

    <template id="custom_title" name="change title" inherit_id="web.layout">
      <xpath expr="//title" position="replace">
        <title>Your title</title>
      </xpath>
    </template>

  </data>
</openerp>
```

*Be sure to declare the xml file in the manifest file and reload the module.*

This works for the login page (if the selected database has the module with this change installed) but it won't work in most of the other pages, because when a view is loaded the title is changed dynamically by the javascript client. (to reflect the view you are in, e.g. "Products - Odoo"
 or "Customers - Odoo")

To change that, you have to extend the JS web client and edit it like this:

```js
openerp.your_module_name = function(instance) {
    instance.web.WebClient.include({
        init: function(parent, client_options) {
            this._super(parent, client_options);
            this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Your Title"});
        },
    });
};
```

*Be sure you do all the necessary for odoo to include your js file, see some examples of simple webclient modules, e.g. [web_dialog_size](https://github.com/OCA/web/blob/8.0/web_dialog_size/)*

With these 2 modifications, you should see your custom page title in all the Odoo pages.

Comment: I know it's been quite a while, but how would one do this JS magic in Odoo 9 ?

Comment: Odoo 15-how to change page title?

Answer (score 4):

In Odoo 10, the above solutions does not work. For Odoo 10 we need to edit below JS file

**`addons/web/static/src/js/abstract_web_client.js`**

Change this code:

`this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "`**Odoo**`"});`

With this one:

`this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "`**MyPageTitle**`"});`

After this, you restart your Odoo server to see the changes.

Comment: Worked for me ... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I was digging on version 9 community edition you need to look at the file:

addons/web/static/src/js/web_client.js

Change this code:

this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Odoo"});

With this one:

this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "MyPageTitle"});

Answer (score -1):

1- In addons/web/static/src/js/chrome.js: 
Search all words containing "Odoo" and replace

2- after :
Search en local modules --> a module named "**Web**" --> upgrade

Comment: You shouldn't edit the source code of Odoo directly but make your changes in external addons, so that you can upgrade Odoo without losing any change. Check my answer to see how you can do this without touching the Odoo source code.