# Odoo 9 Change Backend Page Title

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to change the backend page title in Odoo without much luck. I have already altered  `/addons/web/views/webclient_templates.xml` as suggested here:
 [Odoo 8 - how to change page title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974431/odoo-8-how-to-change-page-title)
with no effect. I am unable to locate the "chrome.js" file however, and it looks like it does not exist in Odoo 9. Can anyone tell me which file contains the functionality of chrome.js in odoo9 or suggest an alternative method to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you find anything? Please post the answer if you did!

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 9, the file containing the `title_part` setting is located at

```
web/static/src/js/web_client.js
```

[More info on GitHub src](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/web/static/src/js/web_client.js#L50)

In Odoo 10 and 11, it's in

```
web/static/src/js/abstract_web_client.js
```

[More info on GitHub src](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/web/static/src/js/abstract_web_client.js#L54)

Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to touch the Odoo's core code, but modifying these JS files is also a not bad workaround for now.

*PS: Since Odoo 11 is on a very active development, I didn't give the exact link to the src. It's easy to find though.*

Answer (score -1):

Try This code may be help you:

```xml
<template id="company_logo_show" inherit_id="website.layout_logo_show" customize_show="True" name="Show Logo">
    <xpath expr="//a[contains(@class, 'navbar-brand')]" position="replace">
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll logo" href="#page-top">
            <img src="/website_itforum/static/src/img/ITFGC_logo.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </xpath>
</template>
```