# Changing Odoo 9 "login title"

Tags: python, odoo-9

I was following this post [Odoo 8 - how to change page title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974431/odoo-8-how-to-change-page-title/29182681#29182681) on how to change Odoo 9 login title . I believe I followed the steps and also restarted the server, but the title didn't change. Any suggestions?

Here are steps I followed:

1. I created a new folder/module called brin in addons folder
2. Created a new xml file(with new title) in that folder that looks like this

[image: brin.xml]

3. Created an **openerp**.py file in that folder and declared the xml file that looks like this:

[image: __openerp__.py file]

Comment: Please show your code not as image so people can copy it and test it. This may be why you are getting downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured found a way to do it.

1.Click the drop down menu on administrator(In the upper right corner).

2.Click the "about" link and activate developer mode.

3.Now go to settings,User interface,Views.Type "layout" in search bar.A set of layouts is brought.Click on Web layout.Click edit.In the xml change the title to custom title.

4.Walaaaa !!